# How to trigger a script when a certain function targets the scripts parent element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, triggers, event-handling, dom-events

I need to trigger a script inside of another element, when that element becomes a target of certain function.

```
<div id="myParent">
    <script>
       //listens for myFunction(myParent) {
            Alert("myParent was target of myFunction")
         }      
    </script>
</div>

function myFunction(target){
    //do something with the target
}
```

So the expected/desired result is

```
myFunction("myParent") //"myParent was target of myFunction"
```

So I know how to add event listeners  but none of them really do what I need them to, or at least I wasn't able to find a way to customize them to suit my needs. On the other hand I managed to call the Script by targeting the parenent element, finding the script within it and triggering it using eval(), however I am not a fan of this method as I would have to check every element that gets passed in myFunction() to see if has a condition which triggers its script. Like so:

```
<div id="myElement_1">
    <p>true</p>
    <script>
       //listens for myFunction(myParent) {
            "Alert("Hello")"
         }      
    </script>
</div>

<div id="myElement_2">
    <p>False</p>
    <script>
       //listens for myFunction(myParent) {
            "Alert("World!")"
         }      
    </script>
</div>


function myFunction(target){
    let checkCondition = target.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText
    if(checkCondition === "true"){
        let trigger = target.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
        eval(trigger)
    }
}

myFunction(myElement_1) // "Hello"
myFunction(myElement_2) //
```

Im afraid that using this solution would eventually clog up my code with thousands of checks within my functions, as each potential target has quite unique trigger conditions. So it makes more sense for the  to listen for it's own triggers, I just am not able to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Once a tag `<script>` appears in html (except xss `innerHTML`), it will be forced to run even if you delete the tag.

You can save data into the html tag and call it out by:

```html
<div id="app" data-text="Hello App" />
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#app").getAttribute("data-text"))
```

Or if you really need to run a script, you can lazyly download it with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: Ok in the meantime I have been experimenting further and realized that there is no way to stop a script from runing the moment it comes to existance. However this problem I have solved by storing the function inside a div element  instead and using eval() to read it.

However this still doesnt solve my problem, as I would like for this div element, containing the "function()" to listen for an custom even (his parent being target of a specific other function)